How to get matrix scatter plot with all variables (SAS On Demand)
I'm using SAS On Demand.
I have a dataset of 9 variables. I'm trying to plot a matrix correlation plot.
When I run:
proc corr data=dataset NOSIMPLE PLOTS(MAXPOINTS=6000)=matrix(histogram);
    var MW LogP LogD Hdonors Hacceptors PSA ROT NATOM NRING;
run;

I get the table, as predicted, but the matrix plot only has the first 5 variables.

How could I get the full plot?
Thanks

From the documentation.
NVAR=ALL | n
specifies the maximum number of variables in the VAR list to be displayed in
the matrix plot, where n > 0. The NVAR=ALL option uses all variables in 
the VAR list. By default, **NVAR=5**.


I missed it, thanks.

If I add NVAR=ALL, then the plot disappears. I'm left with just a matrix.

I had to increase the number of points further.
